# Unable to re-generate R.java in android project

Tags: android, adt, access-denied, r.java-file

I am working on one android application. Don't know why but i am not able to regenerate R.java file.

i also searched a lot about it. and also tried all the solutions i got from various place. but R.java is not generated.

if i import my project in another computer, then it is working fine. only have problem in my eclipse. :(

i also solved all the lint errors, warnings and also tried to clean and build project. i also checked my all .xml files as well as all images. all is perfect not any special symbols or uppercase. and and tried all the tricks which i got. but now able to generate R.java file.

please help me.. Thank in advance...

**Edit :**

> right now i am getting one error like
>
> Description Resource Path Location Type Error executing aapt: Cannot
>   run program "..\Android_SDK\build-tools\18.0.1\aapt.exe":
>   CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied: CreateProcess error=5, Access
>   is denied TestProject line 1 Android ADT Problem

Comment: Only in such situations I find usefull to use Android Studio, because it shows you exactly where your error is (even in the XML). Try installing it and check for errors with it. I also stumbled upon such a blasphemy, but The Android Studio have shown me where a not so obvious problem in one of the XML files is.

Answer (score 4):

Occassionally I am also fighting with this issue. Sometimes it's tough, but it's usually that something is wrong with your /res/ files. Usually XMLs.

First try to Clean your build, but you did that already.

Look for malformed XMLs, they do not have to be marked in red at first, but try to open them all if you don't see them popup in red. Check that you don't reference ids to another views in styles.xml, check for invalid characters in keys, check for invalid/unescaped characters in content of xml entities.

Also check properties of your project and make sure that all Java Build Path components are checked (Order and Export). Mainly Android one. Sometimes it happens to me, that it's unchecked making my project unbuildable.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on another computer, it seems the code is fine. The problem seems to be either your toolchain or your Eclipse workspace.

Try the following:

- If you use Android SDK Tools 17 or higher, make sure you install the corresponding Android SDK Build-tools in Android SDK Manager.
- If the above doesn't help, create a new workspace and import your existing code into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem, which can be caused by many different situations. 
What always worked for me:

If your R.java is not generated, your project is flooded with errors saying that class R is not recognized (obviously). Usually, somewhere between all those R.java errors, there was one other error (with different that all others) which is often overlooked because of hundredths R.java related errors. If i fixed this other error, R.java is generated after clean/build...

Edit: the "other error" i am talking about that is preventing your R.java to regenerate, is often found somewhere inside resource XML files...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your installation path of Eclipse. Just check that your path doesn't have any spaces where you have installed Eclipse. And name should be proper for the Eclipse directory.
      I also had the same problem because my Eclipse installation path got spaces in it, and my Eclipse directory name got changed to some symbolic name. When i renamed it to Eclipse and make the installation which contains no space, it got worked.

For example if Eclipse directory path is like

> D:/New Folder/Android/Eclipse

Then it may got problem because of space between "New Folder".

Check your path and directory name and if it worked then check my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue for past one hour. I just solve it by

1. Remove the ".metadata" file from the workplace directory.
2. Then start the Eclipse.
3. Import the project from the workplace by **File -> Import -> Existing project into workplace under General tab**.

The R.java file will be generated. You need to import all other project that were in your workplace the same way.

Hope this will help someone